# How to access same variable from different variable group Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using azure-pipelines.yaml to build multiple stages each stage having a same variable i.e var_key but different value in each stage for this I have different Azure Library groups

1. dev_group
2. qa_group

azure-pipelines.yaml

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - master

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - master

variables:
  group: group1, group2, group3
  BuildNumber: $(Build.BuildNumber)

stages:
  - stage: debug
    jobs:
      - job: DebugConditions
        pool: 
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - bash: echo $(group1.var_key)

   - stage: dev
    jobs:
      - job: DevConditions
        pool: 
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - bash: echo $(group2.var_key)
```

this is giving me an error, is there an correct way of doing this.

Comment: **What** error is it giving you? You need to fully explain problems including all relevant details.

Comment: You should defined the variable group in the stage scope, like:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#stage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the future, please refer to the [YAML schema documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#variables) before you ask a question about an error with YAML.

A quick review of that document shows that this:

```
variables:
  group: group1, group2, group3
```

is not correct syntax.

> To include variable groups, switch to this sequence syntax:

```
 variables:
 - name: string  # name of a variable   value: string # value of the variable
 - group: string # name of a variable group You can repeat name/value pairs and group.
```

> You can also include variables from templates.

Extrapolating from that,

```
variables:
- group: group1
- group: group2
- group: group3
```

Following the schema is critical when writing YAML configuration documents. It is whitespace sensitive, so be sure you are indenting properly. I recommend using an editor such as VS Code with the Azure Pipelines YAML extension installed to help catch problems like this.

Beyond that, to use a variable group only within a stage, you reference it within the `stage` block:

```
stages: 
- stage: Foo
  variables:
  - group: DEVgroup
```

Again, read the schema documentation. This is all very well documented.

Comment: Hi @Daniel thanks for response, I have already gone through the documentation but I can't find it so I don't want to use template and if I provide - name: string  `# name of a variable value: string # value of the variable` as you said it's like specifying hard coded value but I want to fetch it from group for each stage however my each group contains 10-15 variable so I can't add all variables like name value pair.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I don't understand the problem. Specifying a group will import all the variables in that group, at the scope you specify it at. What is the specific problem you're having that you're trying to solve? Do you want to use only *some* variables from a variable group?

Comment: I want to use all the variables but the problem is variable name in both the group is same I want to use group1 variable in one stage and group2 variable in second stage. If I understand correctly you are trying to say use group in stage scope instead global.

Comment: Yes, you specify the variable group at the scope in which you want to use those variables.The documentation shows which scopes support importing variables.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel I will try and let you know.